# How to to duplicate production database daily with aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Two databases in question here are 'live' and 'prelive'. There's a snapshot taken of the live rds instance early in the morning each day. To get a fresh copy of live data we manually go and delete prelive and create it from fresh using the live snapshot. prelive is mainly used for reproduction of data specific bugs. How can we easily automate the process of getting a fresh prelive instance from the live snapshot every morning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate this process using CloudFormation.

You should create a stack for your 'prelive' environment with a `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` resource. You need to specify the `DBSnapshotIdentifier` property but instead of hard-coding it you will reference a stack parameter, it will look like this:

```yml
Parameters:
  Snapshot:
    Type: String

Resources:
  ...other resources...

  PreliveInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      ...other properties...
      DBSnapshotIdentifier: !Ref Snapshot
      ...other properties...

  ...other resources...
```

This way you can have a Lambda function triggered by a CloudWatch Event every morning that does the following:

1. Look up the `arn` of the latest snapshot of your 'live' environment
2. Update your 'prelive' stack with the `arn` from step 1 as input value for the `Snapshot` parameter.

Because the [`DBSnapshotIdentifier`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsnapshotidentifier) is a property for which an update requires a [replacement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html#update-replacement), a new 'prelive' instance will be created and the old one will be deleted.